# Which preposition follows the word "sequence" said of the relation between things?

Tags: idioms

Can one speak of the sequence (order) *between* two things, or should it be the sequence *of* A and B?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage, you may be interested in our companion site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the sequence *of*. *Sequence* refers to a group of items and the order in which they are found. See, for example, the following [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sequence%20of,%20sequence%20between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):

[image]

Comment: The Ngram presents an irrefutable answer to my question, thank you. I already found out that 'sequence' can refer to a group of things (used as a technical term) or to their order,  the latter seeming to be the more usual meaning.

Comment: Sorry, I was still finding out how all this works...